# Image URL to image replacement

Tags: discussion, images

Many question has image url instead of direct image. Is that right practice to edit those old post and replace url to direct image?

Comment: Worth to mention that many times such images will be broken and lost (aka image rot) in those cases if you want try to look for alternative and if no time for this or no alternative image, remove it from the post altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the posts are usually better with inlined images, be aware that uploading copyrighted images is a breach of the [Stack Exchange TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal). Images hosted on Stack Overflow is released under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license in the same way as any text. You should ask the original poster in a comment before uploading any image that isn't yours.

Directly from the license text:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the
> Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange
> under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.
> [...]
>
> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute
> any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise
> interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party,... (c)
> infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or
> publicity rights of another, ...

With this said, U.S. copyright law have a special clause called [Fair Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) which allows you to use copyrighted content without permission in some cases. It may be possible to upload images under this exception, but it is not applicable for all countries.

The copying is probably considered carried out in the country the user is in. In Sweden, where I am, images are almost never covered by any fair use clause and even very small thumbnails have been considered a copyright infringement in courts.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is! This usually occurs to new users who are not allowed yet to post images...

Just be sure to read over the entire post and fix any other problems you come across... Make sure is not just a minor edit...

Comment: Also don't just use `<img src="old URL here" />` but rather use the image upload screen choose "From Web" so that it will be hosted permanently.